# An unexpected NDSolve behavior

Tags: differential-equations

I observe the following.
The code:

```
 Clear[eq, ic1, ic2, y, t, nds];
eq = y''[t] == -y[t];
ic1 = y[0] == 1;
ic2 = y'[0] == 0;
nds = NDSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, y[t], {t, 0, 30}][[1, 1]]
Plot[Evaluate[y /. nds], {y, 0, 30}]
```

returns this:

[image]

As you see, the equation is that of a harmonic oscillator. One expects a cosine as a solution. But one sees what you see here.
I am at Win7, Mma 10.4.1.0. Finally, this is a fresh session, I did not have a chance to evaluate anything else before this, and, thus, have nothing in Mma memory.

Comment: Should your last line not read `Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. nds], {t, 0, 30}]`? You want to plot as a function of t. Also inside NDSolve you want to solve for `y` not `y[t]`. At least with 10.3 syntax you do

Comment: Or keep it as it is and plot just `Plot[nds[[2]], {t, 0, 30}]`. Eitherway I think your syntax is just a little off. (Although maybe one might expect MMA to be able to figure it out).

Comment: @Quantum_Oli  No, in that case Mma returns the empty plot. And besides, the question is different. Whatever the way I obtained it, the plot should show a cosine, rather than a straight line.

Comment: I have to apologize, the whole question is the result of my stupid mistake `Plot[Evaluate[y /. nds], {y, 0, 30}]` instead of `Plot[Evaluate[y /. nds], {t, 0, 30}]` . I propose to close this question as the one based on a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on MMA 10.3 on OSX 10.10.5

Running your code indeed gives me the same result, a straight line.

However this is not surprising to me as

```
Evaluate[y /. nds]
```

returns, unexpectedly,

> y

Therefore in the plot we are plotting, `y` from 0 to 30, hence a straight line, gradient 1, from 0 to 30...

Furthermore the syntax in your NDSolve is a little off to me. Checking the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html#853395542) we see that the correct syntax is

```
NDSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, y, {t, 0, 30}]
```

not

```
NDSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, y[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

The difference in the outputs is that in the second case a `[t]` is just appended to both sides of the output rule of NDSolve:

> y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 30.}}, <>]

vs

> y[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 30.}}, <>][t]

You can actually use this as we can run either:

```
nds = NDSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, y[t], {t, 0, 30}][[1, 1, 2]];
Plot[Evaluate[nds], {t, 0, 30}]
```

or

```
nds = NDSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, y, {t, 0, 30}][[1, 1]];
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. nds], {t, 0, 30}]
```

and get the same output:

[image]

Note I'm plotting over `t`, not `y`.

Maybe I've missed something more subtle in your question but it seems to be just a couple of small syntaxy mistakes.

Edit:
If you really want to plot with an independent variable `y` you could even do:

```
nds = NDSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, y, {t, 0, 30}][[1, 1]];
Plot[Evaluate[y /. nds][y], {y, 0, 30}]
```

For the same result (although I'm not sure I'd recommend it)